# .htaccess routing problem with GET method

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, routes

I have a search engine on my page, which starts with a get method. The search part works well, but the routing not. I think, will have the problem in my .htaccess file, which is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So when I click on search button, it redirects me to 
`www.mysite.com/search?keyword=something`. IF I replace it from the URL to `www.mysite.com/search/something` the engine works. So I just need to redirect it from .htaccess. 
What you need to know, is I wrote it in Codeigniter, and the routing part is:

```
$route['/search/(:any)'] = "home/search/$2";
```

Any idea? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Why don't you have your form submit to /search/something  ?

Comment: unclear with your question. Explain what you need to do clearly

Comment: I just need to redirect the URL from www.mysite.com/search?keyword=something to www.mysite.com/search/something via .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

to redirect using php modify your Routes.php file

```
$route['/search/(:any)'] = "home/search/$2";

$route['search']['get'] = function ()
{
    $url='home/search/'.$_GET['keyword'];
    header("Location: $url");
die();
};
```